# Is my approach to this functions proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification

Prove or disprove. Given any set X and given any functions f : X → X, g : X → X, h : X → X, if h is one-to-one and h o f = h o g, then f = g.

**Let x belong to X**

**We know that (h o f)(x) = (h o g)(x)**

**(h o f)(x) = (h o g)(x) —> h(f(x)) = h(g(x))**

**Since h is one-to-one, we can say that f(x) = g(x)**

*Not sure where to go from this point...*

Comment: What is your definition of $f=g$? Isn't it $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$?

Comment: Correct f(x) = g(x) for all x in X. What are you asking?

Comment: Not sure wher to go? Well, since you finished the problem fairly quickly, I'd suggest a nice dinner and maybe a movie?  You certainly don't have any more of this problem to do.

Answer (score 0):

You arrive to the point $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. This is your definition of $f = g$.

Answer (score 0):

Even though $h$ is not assumed to be bijective, $f$ and $g$ must agree for all $x$ in $X$.

Proof:

Suppose there is an $x_0$ where they don't agree. Then

$f(x_0) \ne g(x_0)$

Since $h$ is 1:1,

$h(f(x_0)) \ne h(g(x_0))$

But this contradicts our assumption that $hf = hg$.